# How to fix responsiveness of ag-grid table?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using Ag-grid in Angular6 project. I am facing a problem of ag-grid table responsiveness. When i minimize the browser but it does't show any scrolling. Maximum column goes disappear. But when these code run in to Plunker it shows responsiveness. I can't identify the problem.

I am using these ag-grid version:
   "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
   "ag-grid-angular": "^18.1.0",
   "ag-grid-community": "^19.0.0",
   "ag-grid-enterprise": "^19.0.0",

// my ts file

```js
  private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;

  private columnDefs;
  private rowData;


   public constructor() {
     this.columnDefs = [
        {
            headerName: 'Make',
            field: 'make',
            minWidth: 100,
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Model',
            field: 'model',
            minWidth: 100,
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Price',
            field: 'price',
            minWidth: 100,
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Price',
            field: 'a',
            minWidth: 100,
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Price',
            field: 'b',
            minWidth: 100,
        }

    ];
    this.rowData = [
        {
            make: 'Toyota',
            model: 'Celica',
            price: 35000,
            a: 'aa',
            b: 'bb',
            c: 'cc',
            d: 'dd',
        },
        {
            make: 'Toyota',
            model: 'Celica',
            price: 35000,
            a: 'aa',
            b: 'bb',
            c: 'cc',
            d: 'dd',
        }
    ];

}
```

// my html file

```html
 <ag-grid-angular
       #agGrid
       style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
       id="myGrid"
       class="ag-theme-balham"
       [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
       [rowData]="rowData">
   </ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. It's a package integrated problem. I have deleted ag-grid and ag-grid-enterprise package. then solved the problem.